# Generate a frequency distribution function with given Mean, Median, Std Dev, 1st and 3rd Quartile

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I want to generate plot of a function whose Mean, Median, Std Dev, 1st and 3rd Quartile are given.
How do I generate one?

I tried Gaussian Distribution but there Mean = Median and we don't have control over quartiles.

Edit 1:-
I'm helping my 10th grade cousin with statistics. In one of the question I need to compare the skewness of functions with two different sets of variables (Mean, Median, Std Dev, 1st and 3rd Quartile). I want to show him how the frequency distribution will look like.

I did some research and found some skewed function here https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ptnf1tbdgf

Comment: I think the mods are being pushy here. If anyone had a bit of understanding of *statistics 101* they wouldn't have had closed the question for being unclear. It is clear from the fact that I've got two good answers for the same question.

Comment: There have been times when I have disagreed with hasty closing of statistical questions for lack of specificity or clarity. This is not one of those times.

Answer (score 2):

Both the question of whether it is possible and how to do it will depend on the actual values.  For example if you know the mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ and median $q_{2}$ and quartiles $q_{1}$ and $q_{3}$, then having $\sigma < \frac12(q_{3}-q_{1})$ will be impossible to satisfy.

Here is an a piecewise density function which works if the standard deviation is large enough:

Let $q_0 = \frac{16\mu -3q_3-
4q_2-5q_1 -
\sqrt{96\sigma^2-160\mu^2+32(3\mu-q_2)(q_1+q_2+q_3)+32(\mu q_2-q_3^2-q_1^2)+9(q_3-q_1)^2}}{4}$ and $q_4 = \frac{16\mu -5q_3-
4q_2-3q_1 +
\sqrt{96\sigma^2-160\mu^2+32(3\mu-q_2)(q_1+q_2+q_3)+32(\mu q_2-q_3^2-q_1^2)+9(q_3-q_1)^2}}{4}$.

and then let $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      0 &  \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,x\lt q_0 \\
      \frac{1}{4(q_1-q_0)} & q_0\lt x\lt q_1 \\
      \frac{1}{4(q_2-q_1)} & q_1\lt x\lt q_2 \\
      \frac{1}{4(q_3-q_2)} & q_2\lt x\lt q_3 \\
      \frac{1}{4(q_4-q_3)} & q_3\lt x\lt q_4 \\
      0 & q_4 \lt x 
   \end{cases}$$

This does not work if the square root is of a negative number or if it leads to $q_0 \gt q_1$ or $q_4 \lt q_3$, but otherwise it should.

As an illustration, if say $\mu =10$, $\sigma=3$, $q_1=8$, $q_2=9$, $q_3=12$ then this gives $q_0 = 12-\sqrt{45} \approx 5.2918$ and $q_4 = 10+\sqrt{45} \approx 16.7082$ and that seems to work

Answer (score 0):

**Normal populations.** The two parameters of a normal population are the mean $\mu$ and the standard deviation $\sigma$. As you say, the mean and median are the same. Also, once $\sigma$ is specified, the interquartile range (distance between quartiles) is determined.

For example, if a normal distribution has $\mu = 100, \sigma = 15.$ then its median is $100$ and its interquartile range is about 20.2347 (computation in R):

```
diff(qnorm(c(.25,.75), 100, 15))
[1] 20.23469
```

**Normal samples.** Of course, samples do not exactly imitate the population from which they are drawn, but you need to keep the population characteristics in mind.

For example, if I have a large sample, say of size $n = 10\,000$ from the population $\mathsf{Norm}(100, 15),$ then we can expect its mean and median both to be near 100, its standard deviation to be near 15 and its IQR to be near 20.2.

```
set.seed(2020)
x = rnorm(10^4, 100, 16)
mean(x);  median(x)
[1] 99.83717         # sample mean
[1] 99.48441         # sample median
sd(x);  diff(quantile(x, c(.25,.75)))
[1] 15.9507          # sample SD
      75% 
21.43506             # sample IQR
```

**Artificial samples to specification.** If you want to *contrive* a normal *sample* of size $n=10$
to have $\bar X = 100$ and $S_X = 15$ (both almost exactly), then you can start with a sample of size ten from a standard normal distribution, and rescale it appropriately:

```
set.seed(1223)
z1 = rnorm(10)
```

First, rescale so that the sample mean is $0$ and the sample SD is $1.$

```
sd(z1)
[1] 0.7214513
z2 = z1/sd(z1);  sd(z2)
[1] 1
mean(z2)
[1] -0.2631234
z = z2 - mean(z2)
mean(z); sd(z)
[1] 2.218549e-17  # essentially 0
[1] 1
```

Then, rescale to make sample `x` with $\bar X = 100$
and $S_X = 15.$

```
x = 15*z + 100
mean(x);  sd(x)
[1] 100
[1] 15
```

But now you're pretty much stuck with whatever the median and IQR
happen to be; in this particular example, about 99.38 and 23.34, respectively.

```
median(x);  diff(quantile(x, c(.25,.75)))
[1] 99.38192
     75% 
23.33596
```

[You might try to make adjustments to *individual observations* in the *sample* `x` to change the median and IQR, *without changing* $\bar X$ and $S_X,$ but that would be a tedious project, and strictly speaking, the resulting sample would no longer be normal.]

Comment: I don't wan't a normal distribution. Since the mean and median are different, It'll definitely be a skewed function.

Comment: The method works with non-normal distributions. It would help if you can be more specific. However, few distribution families have enough parameters fo allow you to specify mean, median, SD, and IQR completely at will.

Comment: Can you please give any specific examples?